# Scanner and reading from a file

Tags: java

i have to parse a text file using the Scanner, I know how to use the delimiter to parse the text, but i don't know how to make my program accept a file.txt as an input and then to start chopping it off.
Can anyone help me with this? Tnx in advance!

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? Please clarify.

Comment: I am stuck at the very beginning, for example i know how to make it exempt input from my keyboard, but how to make it except a file.txt as an input to the scanner..

Comment: I think people may be confused by your spelling. Do you mean "Accept" as in it accepts your input/file or "exempt" as in, not include it, or do you mean "except" as in everything except that input?

Comment: hahaha, indeed! I mean accept:)) sorry for the confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the Scanner API. It has a constructor that will accept a File parameter. Use it.

```
String fileName = "fileName.txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Would that read just the specified by name file? or would it read any file? tnx for the answer!

Comment: @user3710255: you should be able to figure that out with a little initiative and trial. Give it a go.